# RewriteRule based on multiple conditions

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't seem to figure out how to get these conditions to happen with my .htaccess

```
http://example.com/index.php?page=about
to
http://example.com/about
```

and at the same time

```
http://example.com/index.php?process=login
to
http://example.com/p/login
```

I have tried to do this myself but I couldn't figure out how to do both at the same time.

Using Apache

Comment: Show us the rewrite rules you've tried. There are many examples on the web of doing rewrites like these

Comment: Check this, hope it will help you.... http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files/

Comment: @user2153663 i tell you the simple way to rewrite your urls. My concern is that you will know about it how it works. There are many ways to rewrite urls. You may also make generic script that will run foll all pages.it would be better to read URL Rewriting Guide. i have post link in below answers. thanks

Comment: Here is rule for you
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^p/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?process=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Legend. Spent about 2 hours reading. _I don't really get the language_. a ***Lifesaver*** you are mate.

Comment: Well. Thought it worked but now its just giving me a 500 error. Had a good look and I dont see anything wrong with the .htaccess file. The file only includes what you have posted here.

Comment: Actually I had missed an `[OR]` from my first login that is fixed now. Can you try again?

Comment: Thanks that was it. Great job and Tanks for your help. I don't often do this bit so I was a bit lost.

Comment: Yes it is surprising for me to see a downvote on a working answer :)

Answer (score 2):

**THE SIMPLEST CASE**

The simplest case of URL rewriting is to rename a single static Web page, and this is far easier than the B&Q example above. To use Apache’s URL rewriting function, you will need to create or edit the .htaccess file in your website’s document root (or, less commonly, in a subdirectory).

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule   about   index.php?page=about
RewriteRule   login   index.php?process=login
```

**USING REGULAR EXPRESSIONS**

In URL rewriting, you need only match the path of the URL, not including the domain name or the first slash

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule   ^about/?$   index.php?page=about  [NC]
RewriteRule   ^login/?$   index.php?process=login  [NC]
```

You can also do it as

> example.com/index.php?page=about
>   to
>   example.com/about.html 
>   **OR**
>   example.com/about

using this rule

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

**OR**

```
 RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Here are some usefull links

- [URL Rewriting for Beginners](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)
- [Apache Module mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)
- [URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Cheers!

Mudassar Ali

Comment: Ok, First. thanks for this it will work for what I want but I will have to repeat this for all my pages.

second, I would like the script to be universal.

Comment: You can also do it as 
http://example.com/index.php?page=about
to
http://example.com/about.html

using this rule
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]

it would be Universal for all page. and try same for process.
i think you will be understand how to rewrite urls 
thanks